# LaTeX creating unnecessary space

Tags: spacing, floats

I'm getting unnecessary white spaces as in the snapshot.

[image]

It's mainly because of my figures. I'm putting my figures as

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\input{figures/,,,,,,.tex}
\caption[h]{....}
\end{figure}
```

I'm putting with the `[H]` only because I want them to be the order I'm adding them. Is there any way to achieve the same thing but not have the white spaces?

Comment: Not really, without switching to `\raggedbottom`. Leave figures float: reference to them with `\ref`, the caption serves exactly to the purpose of explaining the figure even if it's not at the point its referenced.

Comment: LaTeX never re-orders figures, `H` just means that you _want_ massive white space rather than let latex move the figures (keeping the order) to get better page breaks, `H` was not one of my better ideas, don't use it:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LaTeX never re-orders figures, `H` just means that you want massive white space rather than let latex move the figures (keeping the order to get better page breaks.

`H` was not one of my better ideas, don't use it:-)